# Parameter unreachable - [ts] cannot find name 'product'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to add my parameter `product` to my Button-component

My function `handleIncrement` has `product` set as follow:

```
handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };
```

My onClick event: `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}`

And from my understanding should make it reachable in my `render()` but Typescript is giving me *"Cannot find name 'Product'"*

Im still at a learning phase for both React and Typescript.
Am I doing something wrong or have I got it all wrong?

This is the complete code:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  };

  renderTags() {
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) return <p>No tags!</p>;
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
          <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        {(this.state.tags.length === 0 && "Please create new tag!") ||
          "tags exists"}
        {this.renderTags()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  private getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: What do you expect `product` to be in the `onClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, variables can be scoped globally, within a function or within a block, depending on how or where they are declared.

```js
var globalVar = 1;

function example() {
  var functionVar = 2;
  
  if (functionVar) {
    let blockVar = 3; // let makes a variable "block-scoped"
  }
}
```

Within any particular scope, you have access to variables defined in that scope but also all scopes above it, up to the global scope (global variables are visible everywhere).

```js
var globalVar = 1;

function example() {
  // here we also have access to globalVar, since it's in an upper scope
  var functionVar = 2;
  
  if (functionVar) {
  // here we have access to globalVar and functionVar, since they are both in an upper scope
    let blockVar = 3;
  }
}
```

In the `render` method of your component, you are using a variable named `product` but you are not defining it anywhere within the scope of `render` (or in a scope above):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <button
        {/* ... */}
        onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
        {/*                                 ^^^^^^^ not defined anywhere in this scope */}
      >
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's an example of how that breaks:

```js
function render() {
  console.log(product);
}

render();
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. Im curious if something about this has changed in the last 6 months since I the material Im learning from does write it as I wrote my code without defining it anywhere, so my understanding was that I didn't have to if I used it like this.